# how to Use CSS only to add the appropriate logo images each p

Tags: css

Use CSS only to add the appropriate logo image next to each solution. This means that you won’t be adding an  tag to the page to get the image to appear. It will be added using CSS and formatted with CSS as well. Solution must be moved over to the right so that the image is isolated as shown in the image below.
So it has to be one class for three paragraphs, and i cant use html, and it has to be three different images

Comment: Is this homework? It sounds like homework... What have you tried? Have you considered looking at some of the CSS properties like `background` to see how you might get around using an explicit `<img>` tag?

Comment: so the problem is i cant use img

Comment: it has to be only in css

Comment: We can't help you without any doe of your own. What is the HTML markup you have so far? Where are the logo images? CSS does nothing on it's own it needs HTML to work with.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I'm saying, consider looking at things like the CSS `background` or `background-image` style to see how you might use an image without an actual HTML `<img>` tag. Additionally, pseudoselectors like `::after` and `::before` can be used to insert content prior to existing elements that exist.

Comment: <div id="main"> 
        <p has to be added image>vProspect 2.0<br>
        Define and research your target audience, define your strategy to audience.</p><p has to be added image >vConvert 2.0<br>
        Create a highly user-friendly and easy-to-navigate information architecture that will help your prospects interact with the company on a highly interactive level.</p>
        <p has to be added image >vRetain 1.0<br>
        Build on existing customer relationships to improve productivity
                  </div>

Comment: and they all has to be different images

Comment: "Solution must be moved over to the right so that the image is isolated as shown in the image below".... what image below? This is obviously a cut and paste job from a homework assignment, how are you meant to learn if we do your work for you?

Comment: I doubt if your teacher would have given you this homework without providing any information in class or readings about possible ways to deal with it. Why don't you go back and review the class materials? Also, it's hard for us to answer this question without seeing the "image below" that you refer to.

Comment: I can't help myself.... here is something intentionally broken : https://jsfiddle.net/vk54xv10/ . It should be enough to get you started. Read up on what I've used at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS. Fix it and you will be on your way.

Answer (score 0):

homework??  try

```
:after
```

or

```
:before
```

and

```
background-image
```